# Polars Advanced Customized Expression Extension

Tags: python, python-polars

I want to construct a series of **customized Polars Expression Extension** following [this tutorial](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api.html).

This my attemp to create customized Polars Expressions:

```py
import polars as pl

@pl.api.register_expr_namespace("EWSD")
class ExponentialMovingStd:
    def __init__(
        self,
        expr: pl.Expr,
        *,
        alpha: float | None = None,
        span: int | None = None,
        half_life: int | None = None,
        **ewm_std_kwargs,
    ):
        self._expr = expr
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.span = span
        print(self.span)
        self.half_life = half_life
        self.ewm_std_kwargs = ewm_std_kwargs
        
        return (self._expr
                .ewm_std(
                    alpha=self.alpha,
                    span=self.span,
                    half_life=self.half_life,
                    **self.ewm_std_kwargs
                    )
                ).cast(pl.UInt8)

    """def __call__(self) -> pl.Expr:
        return (self._expr
                .ewm_std(
                    alpha=self.alpha,
                    span=self.span,
                    halflife=self.halflife,
                    **self.ewm_std_kwargs
                    )
                ).cast(pl.UInt8)"""
```

However, when I use this expression:

```py
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("var").EWSD(span=21).alias("21span_var")
)
```

The `print("self.span")` gives me `None` as it is not defined upon `calling` the expression.

I would like to have:

1. Additional variables to be initialized under `__init__` other than `expr`.
2. A working `__call__` or equivalent so that I dont have to write additional expressions like `pl.col().EWSD().get_values()` to get the values.

Comment: The tutorial is for creating a custom namespace - `EWSD` in your case is the name of the namespace but they are not designed to be called directly. You have a namespace name and then your function name e.g. `pl.col().my_name.EWSD()`

Comment: If you want to add a custom function you can just assign it e.g. `pl.Expr.EWSD = ...` - is that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Also, you'll need to pass the additional variables exactly once. Hence, what is speaking again passing the variables to `__call__` instead of `__init__`?

Comment: @jqurious yes that’s what I want to achieve

Comment: @hericks the __init__ method does not initialize parameters other than expr

Comment: @KevinLi Yes - I was wondering why you prefer passing the parameters to `__init__`, if you can pass them to `__call__` instead. You won't reuse the initialized object again, so any variables initialized under `__init__` won't be persistent anyway, no?